# OneNote - complete listing of the Property IDs

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

I am trying to write a parser for OneNote files.

I would like to get a complete list of all the Property IDs to Property Name.

Here is what I have so far: https://github.com/nddipiazza/onenote-parser-java/blob/5e291a7e6666b4ee62e0f13d9422ca5b4f223e6f/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/onenote/Properties.java

But I cannot find various other ones that appear in documents, such as `0x348b`.

Where can I find a complete, definitive list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah I just didn't google hard enough.

Here it is:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-one/e9bf7da8-7aab-4668-be5e-e0c421175e3c?redirectedfrom=MSDN

My list was complete from the above link.